# Table cells automatic align right

Tags: java, swing, jtable, alignment

Hi I am having this issue where my cells in my JTable automatic aligns right, only in the first column after an event. I am using my TableModel from my other class as well as the table. I can show you the code of my other class if you want to see it.

I have tried to set alignment with this code:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer leftRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
leftRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(leftRenderer);
```

That didn't solve it either.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

import mappers.MemberMapper;
import domains.Member;

public class EditMemberGUI {
    private JFrame editMemberFrame;
    private JPanel btnsPanel, panel;
    private JButton editBtn, cancelBtn;
    private JLabel fNameLbl, lNameLbl, addressLbl, zipCodeLbl, cityLbl, emailLbl,
                    phoneNoLbl;
    private JTextField fNameTF, lNameTF, addressTF, zipCodeTF, cityTF, emailTF,
    phoneNoTF; ;
    private GridLayout layout;

    public EditMemberGUI(final ShowMembersGUI gui) {

        layout = new GridLayout(0,2,1,0);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setVgap(0);

        fNameLbl = new JLabel("Fornavn: ");
        fNameTF = new JTextField(15);

        lNameLbl = new JLabel("Efternavn: ");
        lNameTF = new JTextField(15);

        addressLbl = new JLabel("Adresse: ");
        addressTF = new JTextField(15);


        zipCodeLbl = new JLabel("Postnummer: ");
        zipCodeTF = new JTextField(15);

        cityLbl = new JLabel("By: ");
        cityTF = new JTextField(15);

        emailLbl = new JLabel("Email: ");
        emailTF = new JTextField(15);

        phoneNoLbl = new JLabel("Telefonnr: ");
        phoneNoTF = new JTextField(15);

        panel.add(fNameLbl);
        panel.add(fNameTF);
        panel.add(lNameLbl);
        panel.add(lNameTF);
        panel.add(addressLbl);
        panel.add(addressTF);
        panel.add(zipCodeLbl);
        panel.add(zipCodeTF);
        panel.add(cityLbl);
        panel.add(cityTF);
        panel.add(emailLbl);
        panel.add(emailTF);
        panel.add(phoneNoLbl);
        panel.add(phoneNoTF);


        //------------

        btnsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

        editBtn = new JButton("Redigér");
        editBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
                int zipCode = Integer.parseInt(zipCodeTF.getText());
                Member m = new Member(fNameTF.getText(), lNameTF.getText(), 
                        addressTF.getText(), zipCode, cityTF.getText(),
                        emailTF.getText(), phoneNoTF.getText());
                MemberMapper mMapper = new MemberMapper();
                int i = gui.getIndex();
                mMapper.editMember(m, i);

                editMemberFrame.setVisible(false);


                List<Member> data = mMapper.selectAllMembers();
                MyTableModel myTableModel = new MyTableModel(data);

                gui.getTable().setModel(myTableModel);
                int row = gui.getTable().getSelectedRow();
                myTableModel.tableUpdate(row, m);

            }   
        });

        cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                editMemberFrame.setVisible(false);
            }   
        });

        btnsPanel.add(editBtn);
        btnsPanel.add(cancelBtn);

    }

    public void showGUI() {

        editMemberFrame = new JFrame();
        editMemberFrame.setTitle("Redigér Medlem");
        editMemberFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        editMemberFrame.setSize(400,300);

        editMemberFrame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        editMemberFrame.add(btnsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //editMemberFrame.pack();
        editMemberFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JTextField getfNameTF() {
        return fNameTF;
    }

    public void setfNameTF(JTextField fNameTF) {
        this.fNameTF = fNameTF;
    }

    public JTextField getlNameTF() {
        return lNameTF;
    }

    public void setlNameTF(JTextField lNameTF) {
        this.lNameTF = lNameTF;
    }

    public JTextField getAddressTF() {
        return addressTF;
    }

    public void setAddressTF(JTextField addressTF) {
        this.addressTF = addressTF;
    }

    public JTextField getZipCodeTF() {
        return zipCodeTF;
    }

    public void setZipCodeTF(JTextField zipCodeTF) {
        this.zipCodeTF = zipCodeTF;
    }

    public JTextField getCityTF() {
        return cityTF;
    }

    public void setCityTF(JTextField cityTF) {
        this.cityTF = cityTF;
    }

    public JTextField getEmailTF() {
        return emailTF;
    }

    public void setEmailTF(JTextField emailTF) {
        this.emailTF = emailTF;
    }

    public JTextField getPhoneNoTF() {
        return phoneNoTF;
    }

    public void setPhoneNoTF(JTextField phoneNoTF) {
        this.phoneNoTF = phoneNoTF;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the code that builds the actual data for the table, but I assume the datatypes in the row that get right aligned is different.   The default implementation of the `getColumnClass()` method is possibly assigning that column a different renderer.  To confirm this try swapping columns in your the data you pass to the data model and see if the right-alignment moves with the same data.

Specifying your own renderer should fix the issue, but another solution would be to extend the `DefaultTableModel` and specifically define the class of the first column in the `getColumnClass()` mehtod.

Comment: Isn't it weird that it's only the first column which does it?

Comment: I somehow fixed it by changing the column class. :) Thank you!

Comment: @Ilhami Integer.class and other numbers are aligned right in a table cell. Object.class and String.class shouldn't.

Comment: @LeoPflug yeah I realized that. I think that's weird though.

Comment: It's one standardized way of aligning numbers in tables.

Answer (score 1):

For this purposes you need your own `TableCellRenderer` or you can override `getTableCellRendererComponent()` method of  `DefaultTableCellRenderer`, for example:

```
private TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer() {
    return new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1, boolean arg2, boolean arg3, int arg4, int arg5) {
             //logic for Alignment
             setHorizontalAlignment(left ? JLabel.LEFT : JLabel.RIGHT);
             return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5);
        }
    };
}
```

here `left` is boolean variable as a flag for alignment.

EDIT:
Try it here like you post :

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(getCellRenderer());
```

`getCellRenderer()` return renderer for your column, you needt to call its methods by yourself.

EDIT:
here is an example

```
public class Form extends JFrame {

    private Boolean left = true;

    public Form(){

        final JTable t = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},new Object[]{"a","b","c"}));
        t.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(getCellRenderer());
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(t));
        JButton change = new JButton("change");
        change.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                left = !left;
                t.repaint();
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(change,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer() {
        return new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1, boolean arg2, boolean arg3, int arg4, int arg5) {
                 setHorizontalAlignment(left ?JLabel.LEFT :  JLabel.RIGHT);
                 return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Form();
    }
}
```

Comment: How should I call that method?

    getCellRenderer().getTableCellRendererComponent(gui.getTable(), value, true, true, row, column); What should be in value?

Comment: Nothing/Leave it as it is. You're overriding the function for the need of your own special TableCellRenderer Class.